# How to write select with case in datatable using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to filter the data in the datatable with some condition but the condition are using case condition as shown below

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["FilteredData"];

string expression = string.Format("MAKER_BY = CASE WHEN '" + MakerBy.Trim() + "'='A' THEN MAKER_BY ELSE '"+ MakerBy.Trim() + "' END");

dt = dt.Select(expression).CopyToDataTable();
```

When executing the above code I'm getting error saying, Missing operand after 'WHEN' operator.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Show the full text of your query, not just a line. Also be sure to have your strings for fields whitelisted to avoid sql injection

Comment: We need more context. Is this a part of an SQL query sent to the database, or is this a filter expression to a data table?

Comment: Maybe `MakerBy` is empty string?

Comment: Don't concat your queries, it makes your code vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). Use prepared statements instead.

Comment: Its a filter expression to datatable @ZoharPeled

Comment: Case WHEN is not supported for the DataTable.Select RowFilter See  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Filter expressions does not support `CASE`.
However, They do support `IIF`.

For more information, read the relevant Microsoft docs page: [DataColumn.Expression Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Data_DataColumn_Expression).

So you can do it like this:

```
string expression = string.Format("MAKER_BY = IIF('" + MakerBy.Trim() + "'='A', MAKER_BY, '"+ MakerBy.Trim() + "')");
```

However, there is an easier way:

```
string expression = "MAKER_BY = '"+ MakerBy.Trim() +"' OR '"+ MakerBy.Trim() +"' = 'A'";
```